# How to create a new List of files and return them?

Tags: file, applescript

I'm using the following AppleScript in my Automator workflow:

```
on run {input, parameters}
  --say input
  set result_array to {} as list
  try
      repeat with this_file in input
          tell application "Image Events"
              launch
              set this_image to open this_file
              copy dimensions of this_image to {W, H}
              close this_image
          end tell

          set text item delimiters to ":"
          set file_name to last text item of (this_file as string)
          set text item delimiters to ""
          set filter_string to W & "x" & H as string

          if file_name contains filter_string then
              set the end of result_array to this_file
          end if
  end repeat
  return result_array
  on error error_message
      display dialog error_message
  end try
end run
```

The script runs after a `Get Folder Contents` action.

There is something wrong with the result array but I can't figure out what.
The result has to be a list of files which have their size in their names.

Comment: i want the specific `this_file` in the `result_array`, but it dosn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly use one of the following :

```
if file_name contains filter_string then
 -- set the end of result_array to this_file as alias
 -- set the end of result_array to this_file as text
end if
```

Currently `this_file` is like a pointer to the original list of files. When used directly it includes the index of the current value and the full list.

This is probably due to how the `repeat with a in b` is implement in Applescript.